# Count different totals from multiple tables in mysql grouped by user_id in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count user_id from `courses_taken` and `quiz_attempts` table but my query brings me wrong numbers.

```
SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.email,
    u.user,
    u.joined,
    MAX(qa.last_attempt_time) as last_attempt_time, 
    COUNT(qa.user_id) total_quiz, 
    COUNT(ct.user_id) total_courses 
FROM users u

LEFT JOIN courses_taken ct
ON u.id = ct.user_id

LEFT JOIN quiz_attempt qa
ON u.id = qa.user_id AND qa.attempt_mode=1

GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY total_courses DESC
```

### **Table structure**

`users` table

`id, email, user, joined`

`quiz_attempt` table

`id,user_id, last_attempt_time, attempt_mode etc.`

`courses_taken` table

`id,user_id,course_id,taken_on etc.`

---

Here i am trying to get all users with their total number of quiz attempts and total number of courses taken. But my query returns same numbers for both quiz attempts and courses taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use `COUNT DISTINCT` on a column which varies uniquely with the value that you are trying to count, i.e.:

```
...
COUNT(DISTINCT qa.id) total_quiz, 
COUNT(DISTINCT ct.course_id) total_courses 
...
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66834/1)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a cartesian product problem because of the join.  The better solution is to pre-aggregate the results.  However, in many cases if the tables are not too big, then `count(distinct)` solves the problem:

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, u.user, u.joined,
       MAX(qa.last_attempt_time) as last_attempt_time, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT qa.id) as total_quiz, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT ct.id) as total_courses 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     courses_taken ct
     ON u.id = ct.user_id LEFT JOIN
     quiz_attempt qa
     ON u.id = qa.user_id AND qa.attempt_mode = 1
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY total_courses DESC;
```

Note that this works because you are using `MAX()` and `COUNT()`.  It would not work with `SUM()` or `AVG()`.

Comment: I guess `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)` will always return 1 given that OP is also joining and grouping by `user_id` - will need to count distinct on something which varies.

Comment: this query returns 1 every time

Comment: @FaizAli . . . I fixed that.  The counts need to be on the ids in the tables, not on the key used for joining them.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put distinct on the user_ID column but put it on the id for that table like this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.email, u.userid, u.joined,
MAX(qa.last_attempt_time) as last_attempt_time, 
COUNT(DISTINCT qa.id) as total_quiz, 
COUNT(DISTINCT ct.id) as total_courses 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
courses_taken ct
ON u.id = ct.user_id LEFT JOIN
quiz_attempt qa
ON u.id = qa.user_id AND qa.attempt_mode = 1
GROUP BY u.id, u.email, u.userid, u.joined
ORDER BY total_courses DESC;
```

or if this confuses you, you can use subquery like this:-

```
SELECT 
u.id,
u.email,
u.UserId,
u.joined,
qa.last_attempt_time as last_attempt_time, 
qa.total_quizCOUNT,
ct.total_coursesCOUNT 
FROM users u

LEFT JOIN 
(Select user_id, Count(user_id) as total_coursesCOUNT from courses_taken group by user_id) ct
ON u.id = ct.user_id

LEFT JOIN (Select user_id, Count(user_id) total_quizCOUNT, MAX(last_attempt_time) as last_attempt_time from quiz_attempt  where attempt_mode = 1 group by user_id) qa
ON u.id = qa.user_id

ORDER BY total_coursesCOUNT DESC
```